# Mulesoft displaying null values for nested properties in an array (even though it displays those values when i refer to the outer property.)

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I have an issue reading nested property values.
I have transformed the inbound message into the following structure - however when i read the inner properties as map it shows them as null.. but if i directly pull the parent in reference I can see the inner values.
INBOUND payload :

```js
    [
  {
    "Name": "C-name1",
    "child": [
      {
        "ProductMessage__r": {
          "ProductMessageText__c": "testvalues",
          "Id": null,
          "type": "ProductMessage__c"
        },
        "Id": null,
        "type": "CallMessage__c",
        "Product__r": {
          "Id": null,
          "type": "Product__c",
          "Name": "stackov"
        }
      },
      {
        "ProductMessage__r": {
          "ProductMessageText__c": "stack overflow",
          "Id": null,
          "type": "ProductMessage__c"
        },
        "Id": null,
        "type": "CallMessage__c",
        "Product__r": {
          "Id": null,
          "type": "Product__c",
          "Name": "stackover"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "callName": "C-02436592",
    "child": [
      {
        "ProductMessage__r": {
          "ProductMessageText__c": "stackover flow",
          "Id": null,
          "type": "ProductMessage__c"
        },
        "Id": null,
        "type": "CallMessage__c",
        "Product__r": {
          "Id": null,
          "type": "Product__c",
          "Name": "cooler"
        }
      },
      {
        "ProductMessage__r": {
          "ProductMessageText__c": "vxcvxcvxc",
          "Id": null,
          "type": "ProductMessage__c"
        },
        "Id": null,
        "type": "CallMessage__c",
        "Product__r": {
          "Id": null,
          "type": "Product__c",
          "Name": "Mixtard® 30 IND"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now in the above payload if i refer to the parent values**(**two, three**)** as following it displays all the values correctly, but if i access the child parameters **(**one, four, five and six**)** :

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var t = payload.values
---
t map((item,index)->{
    callname:t[index].callName,
    childprod2: t[index].child map({
    one:    $. product__r.Name, //diplsys null
    two : $,//displays the entire nested values
    three: t[index].child,
    four : $. product__r, // displays null
    five: $. productmessage__r, //null
    six: $. productmessage__r. ProductMessageText__c //null

    })
    })
```

Here is the output :
It displayed when outer properties are referred. but when i refer the inner properties it shows them as null:

```js
[
  {
    "callname": "C-02436590",
    "childprod2": [
      {
        "one": null,
        "two": {
          " ProductMessage__r": {
            " ProductMessageText__c": "stack overflowtestmix",
            "Id": null,
            "type": " ProductMessage__c"
          },
          "Id": null,
          "type": " CallMessage__c",
          " Product__r": {
            "Id": null,
            "type": " Product__c",
            "Name": " stack overflow 30 IND"
          }
        },
        "three": [
          {
            " ProductMessage__r": {
              " ProductMessageText__c": "stack overflowtestmix",
              "Id": null,
              "type": " ProductMessage__c"
            },
            "Id": null,
            "type": " CallMessage__c",
            " Product__r": {
              "Id": null,
              "type": " Product__c",
              "Name": " stack overflow 30 IND"
            }
          },
          {
            " ProductMessage__r": {
              " ProductMessageText__c": "stack overflowtest",
              "Id": null,
              "type": " ProductMessage__c"
            },
            "Id": null,
            "type": " CallMessage__c",
            " Product__r": {
              "Id": null,
              "type": " Product__c",
              "Name": " stack overflow 30 IND"
            }
          },
          {
            " ProductMessage__r": {
              " ProductMessageText__c": "stack overflow stack overflowtest",
              "Id": null,
              "type": " ProductMessage__c"
            },
            "Id": null,
            "type": " CallMessage__c",
            " Product__r": {
              "Id": null,
              "type": " Product__c",
              "Name": " stack overflow 30 IND"
            }
          }
        ],
        "four": null,
        "five": null,
        "six": null
      },
      {
        "one": null,
        "two": {
          " ProductMessage__r": {
            " ProductMessageText__c": "stack overflowtest",
            "Id": null,
            "type": " ProductMessage__c"
          },
          "Id": null,
          "type": " CallMessage__c",
          " Product__r": {
            "Id": null,
            "type": " Product__c",
            "Name": " stack overflow 30 IND"
          }
        },
        "three": [
          {
            " ProductMessage__r": {
              " ProductMessageText__c": "stack overflowtestmix",
              "Id": null,
              "type": " ProductMessage__c"
            },
            "Id": null,
            "type": " CallMessage__c",
            " Product__r": {
              "Id": null,
              "type": " Product__c",
              "Name": " stack overflow 30 IND"
            }
          },
          {
            " ProductMessage__r": {
              " ProductMessageText__c": "stack overflowtest",
              "Id": null,
              "type": " ProductMessage__c"
            },
            "Id": null,
            "type": " CallMessage__c",
            " Product__r": {
              "Id": null,
              "type": " Product__c",
              "Name": " stack overflow 30 IND"
            }
          },
          {
            " ProductMessage__r": {
              " ProductMessageText__c": "stack overflow stack overflowtest",
              "Id": null,
              "type": " ProductMessage__c"
            },
            "Id": null,
            "type": " CallMessage__c",
            " Product__r": {
              "Id": null,
              "type": " Product__c",
              "Name": " stack overflow 30 IND"
            }
          }
        ],
        "four": null,
        "five": null,
        "six": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "callname": "C-02436592",
    "childprod2": [
      {
        "one": null,
        "two": {
          " ProductMessage__r": {
            " ProductMessageText__c": "stack overflowtestmix",
            "Id": null,
            "type": " ProductMessage__c"
          },
          "Id": null,
          "type": " CallMessage__c",
          " Product__r": {
            "Id": null,
            "type": " Product__c",
            "Name": " stack overflow 30 IND"
          }
        },
        "three": [
          {
            " ProductMessage__r": {
              " ProductMessageText__c": "stack overflowtestmix",
              "Id": null,
              "type": " ProductMessage__c"
            },
            "Id": null,
            "type": " CallMessage__c",
            " Product__r": {
              "Id": null,
              "type": " Product__c",
              "Name": " stack overflow 30 IND"
            }
          },
          {
            " ProductMessage__r": {
              " ProductMessageText__c": "stack overflowtest",
              "Id": null,
              "type": " ProductMessage__c"
            },
            "Id": null,
            "type": " CallMessage__c",
            " Product__r": {
              "Id": null,
              "type": " Product__c",
              "Name": " stack overflow 30 IND"
            }
          },
          {
            " ProductMessage__r": {
              " ProductMessageText__c": "stack overflow stack overflowtest",
              "Id": null,
              "type": " ProductMessage__c"
            },
            "Id": null,
            "type": " CallMessage__c",
            " Product__r": {
              "Id": null,
              "type": " Product__c",
              "Name": " stack overflow 30 IND"
            }
          }
        ],
        "four": null,
        "five": null,
        "six": null
      },
      {
        "one": null,
        "two": {
          " ProductMessage__r": {
            " ProductMessageText__c": "stack overflowtest",
            "Id": null,
            "type": " ProductMessage__c"
          },
          "Id": null,
          "type": " CallMessage__c",
          " Product__r": {
            "Id": null,
            "type": " Product__c",
            "Name": " stack overflow 30 IND"
          }
        },
        "three": [
          {
            " ProductMessage__r": {
              " ProductMessageText__c": "stack overflowtestmix",
              "Id": null,
              "type": " ProductMessage__c"
            },
            "Id": null,
            "type": " CallMessage__c",
            " Product__r": {
              "Id": null,
              "type": " Product__c",
              "Name": " stack overflow 30 IND"
            }
          },
          {
            " ProductMessage__r": {
              " ProductMessageText__c": "stack overflowtest",
              "Id": null,
              "type": " ProductMessage__c"
            },
            "Id": null,
            "type": " CallMessage__c",
            " Product__r": {
              "Id": null,
              "type": " Product__c",
              "Name": " stack overflow 30 IND"
            }
          },
          {
            " ProductMessage__r": {
              " ProductMessageText__c": "stack overflow stack overflowtest",
              "Id": null,
              "type": " ProductMessage__c"
            },
            "Id": null,
            "type": " CallMessage__c",
            " Product__r": {
              "Id": null,
              "type": " Product__c",
              "Name": " stack overflow 30 IND"
            }
          }
        ],
        "four": null,
        "five": null,
        "six": null
      }
    ]
  }
```

The final outcome that i wasnted was that for each call, i have a string of 'product-productmessage, product-productmessage' but even if you just help me access and pull the child values it would be great.

Comment: I get errors trying the input and script. For example, there is no values member in the payload. Please review and fix the errors first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this dataweave to pull child values. Also its better to use item.callName instead of t[index].callName(both are equivalent though). map function itself iterates over each items in an array.

```
    %dw 2.0
    output json
    var t= payload
    ---
    t map(item,index) ->{
    callname:item.callName,
    childproduct2:item.child map {
    one: $.Product__r.Name,
    two:$,
    three:$,
    four: $.Product__r,
    five:$.ProductMessage__r,
    six:$.ProductMessage__r.ProductMessageText__c
    }
  }
```